# Getting an error for 'name not defined' when it has been defined

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop, nameerror

I'm writing code to have users input items/prices/quantities for a grocery list. The while loop is supposed to continue looping until a variable is no longer true. I defined the variable ahead of the while loop (stop=='true') but it keeps coming back as an error for 'stop' not being defined. I've tried all sorts of combos of random things so the code might look crazy by now. Code below. Thanks!

```
grocery_list={}
grocery_history={}

stop == 'true'

while stop == 'true' :
    grocery_item['item_name']=input('Item name:\n')
    grocery_item['quantity']=input('Quantity purchase:\n')
    grocery_item['cost']=input('Price per item:\n')
    grocery_history.append(grocery_item)
    if input('Would you like to enter another item?\nType c for continue or q to quit:\n') == 'q':
       stop=='q'
```

Comment: `==` is the equality operator, not assignment operator

Comment: I tried using = and == and got the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 4 should be: `stop = 'true'`

One `=` is for assignment, `==` is a comparison operator

Comment: When I used = it gave me a syntax error. When I used == it gave me the 'name not defined' error.

Comment: What line is giving you syntax error after you change it to `=`? Keep in mind there are other issues with your code such as not having `grocery_item` defined and attempting to `append` to a dictionary

Comment: Line 6 at the moment (while stop = 'true':).

Comment: That line was fine, as I indicted in my answer the issue was when your declaration of the `stop` variable on line 4. The while loop should remain as is with `==`, but the assignment on line 4 should just use `=`. `==` and `=` are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
message = 'Would you like to...'
items = []
while input(message) != 'q':
    items.append({
         'name': nput('Item name:\n'),
         'quantity': int(input('Quantity purchase:\n')),
         'cost': input('Price per item:\n'),
    })
```